# In php can we access private methods of final class from outside the class?

Tags: php

I have a final class along with its private/public static methods in one file and want to access its private static method in another file. Can I do that? Is this legal access?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: I tried and got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ". So I was not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: trying to access private of some class or whatever is your are trying to do wont give a unexpected token. so here it seems you have missed something.

Comment: The whole point of private methods is that you cannot access them from outside the class.

Comment: That sounds like you have a syntax error. Check the PHP manual for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try altering it at runtime via reflection

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('FinalClassName', 'staticMethodName');
$method->setAccessible(true);

$method->invoke(null, $arg1, $arg2, $etc);
```